# Phonegap/Cordova my camera plugin stopped working on upgrade :(

Tags: cordova

I've been running my app on Phonegap 1.2.0 and decided it was finally time to make the jump to Cordova 1.9.0

I have a plugin which extended the camera (so I could crop etc when a picture is taken) and it seems to have broken with the upgrade (I changed all references to Cordova ie. CDV for PG and cordova for phonegap where needed).  It seems like extending via

```
Camera.prototype.MYFUNCTION
```

just has no effect as accessing "MYFUNCTION" via

```
navigator.camera.MYFUNCTION
```

shows as undefined where it used to show my function

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related but this might have something to do with it.  http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/07/phonegap-android-plugins-sometimes-we.html

The parts of Cordova 2.0.0rc1 are being tagged right now with an aim for it to ship Monday.  2.0.0 is scheduled to launch on Friday at PhoneGap day.  I say try 1.7.1 today, give 2.0.0rc1 a try on Monday, then try 2.0.0 on Friday.